Android Studio Flutter Virtual Device Run Error Gradle 2024
Can anyone help me?
I installed Android Studio Jellyfish and the Flutter SDK. I attempted to run the app on a virtual device and and error is raised referring to the gradle
How do I resolve this issue?
I tried to install past vesions of the sdk via the sdk manager on the SDK platforms tab.. v 13.0 Tiramisu

What's the error?

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1638)
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1646)
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.(ZipFile.java:1484)

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
